# Export MySQL database install script from Webmatrix

Tags: mysql, wordpress, upload, hosting, webmatrix

Does anyone know the trick to force Webmatrix to create the MySQL database install scripts on my local box?  Here is why I ask:

I've found a [Webmatrix help article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/871/publish-your-website/) that says MS Webmatrix  "`publishes the (SQL Server or MySQL) database by creating scripts that run in a database that has been created for you by your hosting provider.`"  That is wonderful, except I can't get it to work when I'm trying to publish a MySQL database (backing wordpress) through FTP (my hosting provider does not support 'web deploy').  Again, no problem, since it is already [documented](http://ruslany.net/2010/07/install-php-applications-with-webmatrix/) that " `FTP protocols cannot be used to publish MySQL database`. "

But this does not excuse Webmatrix from generating MySQL database install scripts for me.  During the publishing step, no database install script is generated - at least that I can tell - **and there is no manual option to create a database export / backup / install script.**

In short, as Webmatrix goes, I'm dead in the water trying to get my database uploaded to my hosting provider.  Does anyone know the trick to force Webmatrix to create the MySQL database install scripts on my local box?  Once created, I can take-over the upload and install process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just open the command line and execute the mysqldump command

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

mysqldump manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a plugin for PHPMyAdmin within Wordpress - Look here..

http://www.blogtycoon.net/wordpress-plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/